# How does Atmel's XMEGA numbering scheme work?

Tags: avr, atmel, xmega

Atmel has several series of XMEGA chips. How does the numbering scheme work?

Comment: I don't see a problem with questions of the format "What's the difference between these two similar part numbers?"

Comment: I have had many times that I have seen odd numbering schemes that are not overly obvious as to what they mean. Asking this type of question can very much help with the electronic design process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nice Atmel brochure](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc7925.pdf). Good general overview and all members of family listed on bottom of page 11.

Whence cometh this ...

[image]

Comment: Try to place comments relating to the validity of the question on the question, not in an answer.

Answer (score 10):

```
ATxmega128A1U
       nnnLms
```

From the current parts list, I gather the first number `nnn` is the amount of flash in kilobytes. The letter `L` is one of `A` or `D`, the cheaper `D` parts have no DMA or DAC. The number `m` is 1, 3, 4 for 100, 64, 44 pin parts, and a `U` suffix signifies a part with USB.